# load effect file for directx shader with 3ds max sdk

Tags: directx, 3dsmax

I am creating a utility plugin for 3ds max using 3ds max SDK in C++. In my plugin, I need to assign directx shader material to some of the selected nodes in the scene. I use the following code to create a directx shader material:

```
Mtl* mtl = (Mtl*)(ip->CreateInstance(MATERIAL_CLASS_ID, kDxMaterialClassID));
IDxMaterial3* dxMtl = (IDxMaterial3*)mtl->GetInterface(IDXMATERIAL3_INTERFACE);
```

The created material use the default shader effect file, in my case, it is %MAXDIR%\maps\fx\default.fx. But how can I load other effect file to this material? 
I searched the 3ds max SDK documentation. The `IDxMaterial3` class provide a function: `GetCurrentParser` which returns an effect parser interface (`class IEffectParser`). The `IEffectParser` provides a function `LoadEffect` which seems to be the correct function to load an effect file.

```
virtual bool LoadEffect ( 
    LPVOID pDevice,     //The DirectX device
    IEffectManager* em, //A pointer to the IEffectManager instance
    const MCHAR* effect,//A string containing the effect - this can either be a filename or a buffer contaning the effect
    bool  fileType,     //Defines whether the string contains a file name or a buffer
    bool  forceReload   //If true don't pull the effect from a cache, you need to reload from disk
)
```

However, the second parameter of the function is an `IEffectManager*` type. I have no idea what it is and how should I get one from the material. 
Am I looking at the right direction ? If not, what is the right way to load an effect file for the directx shader material ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to set the effect file path by using the paramete blocks of the material. I post my solution in case anyone else encounter the same problem:

```
// parameter block index of the effect file
const int kEffectFilePBlockIndex = 1; 

// parameter ID of the effect file option
const int kEffectFileParamID = 0;

bool SimpleShaderAdaptor::apply_shader(INode* node) {

    // create the shader material
    Mtl* mtl = (Mtl*)(ip_->CreateInstance(MATERIAL_CLASS_ID, kDxMaterialClassID)); 
    if( !mtl ) return false;

    // get the material interface
    IDxMaterial3* dxmtl = (IDxMaterial3*)mtl->GetInterface(IDXMATERIAL3_INTERFACE);
    if( !dxmtl ) return false; 

    // set the effect file path
    IParamBlock2* pb = mtl->GetParamBlock(kEffectFilePBlockIndex);
    BOOL ret = pb->SetValue(kEffectFileParamID, 
                            ip_->GetTime(), 
                            fx_filepath_.c_str()); // The Effect file path to be set
    if( ret == FALSE ) return false;

    node->SetMtl(mtl);
    return true;
}
```

the effect file parameter of the directx shader material is in the 1st parameter block with ParamID = 0. By setting the value of that parameter, you can load the specifit effect file.